# Why does my procedural texture look different after cell fracture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, scale, procedural

I've got a character out of MakeHuman that I want to break apart like a statue. I've applied a procedural stone texture to the character.

[image: MakeHuman character with texture]

I applied the armature modifier, then separated the hand (the part I want to break apart) into a new object.

[image: Hand is separated for fracture]

With the hand object selected, I broke it apart with the cell fracture addon. After the fracture, the new pieces aren't textured the same as the rest of the arm, or the original hand. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use procedural textures the texture coordinates are based on the object's position, rotation and size. When you shatter the object it will turn into many objects with different position. It can be solved by using the Texture Coordinate node's Object output using a common object as reference. This will however not solve the problem once you move the parts away. The texture will "slide".
You will need to create UV coordinates and bake down your procedural texture to an image and have this applied as a new material.

Answer (score 1):

After a good night's sleep, I woke up with a pretty simple solution to my problem. Instead of UV unwrapping the hand, or even worse, hundreds of individual objects from the fracture, I just duplicated my procedural material and adjusted the scaling of various nodes to roughly match the scaling of the original material. No UV unwraps. No baking. No texture sliding. Still procedural. Problem solved.

[image]